# Does boosting circuit requires a switch for not draining the current? Is there any anoter alternative for this case?

Tags: led, boost, lipo

Iam using 134n3p module to boost the voltage from 3.7v to 5v and using that 5v to light up SMD LEDs.
I removed the 5V USB hub and connected the 5V and GND pins to my LED circuit.

When I am connecting the battery to B+ and B- pins of the module, it is taking around 19mA (calculated) and my battery is getting drained very fastly (Im using 350mAh Lipo battery). So, a switch needs to be used in between to stop thr draining.

**So, instead of using a switch between **battery and B+ pin**, is there a way we can make the current 0mA?**

**Can we use MOSFET as a auto switch? what would be the schematic in that case?**

The link below is the 134n3p module.
http://www.centiot.com/134n3p-5v-step-module-lithium-battery-charging-protection-board-boost-converter-led-indicator-diy-power-bank.

I am planning to make custom PCB so that I can put my LED circuit and 134n3p module together on same PCB.
Been searching in the internet, but I couldn't the IC which they are using in the circuit.

**It would be helpful for me if I can get the schematic of the module.**

Comment: Many of these ICs have "standby" modes or "enable" pins which allow you to shut them down and use no power. However, you'll need to find the schematic ..